# Create Aspose.Email attachment from contentBytes in Java

Tags: java, email-attachments, aspose

I know that we can create an aspose email attachment using the below code:

```
//Create an instance of Attachment class
Attachment attachment;

//Load an attachment
attachment = new Attachment("1.txt");
```

My question is if I don't have the attachment path or URL but only the name of the file and the content body bytes, how to create the attachment in this case?

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://reference.aspose.com/email/java/com.aspose.email/Attachment)? You can use [`Attachment(InputStream, String)`](https://reference.aspose.com/email/java/com.aspose.email/Attachment#Attachment(java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String)) (or one of the other constructors accepting an input stream) for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass file name and stream of your file content in [Attachment](https://reference.aspose.com/email/java/com.aspose.email/Attachment) class.  For more detail, please read following article.

[Working with Message Attachments](https://docs.aspose.com/email/java/working-with-message-attachments/)

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.